# Simplification to avoid 1/0

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Is there a way I can get Mathematica to simplify the following equation so I can avoid $1/0$ errors later?

The command I used is:

```
Assuming[nx > 0, FullSimplify[nx \[Mu]x]]
```

The result I get:

```
-((1284.57 (0.216577 + (2.0697*10^-19 nx^(1/3))/Sqrt[
     2.16335*10^-36 + 9.13257*10^-37 nx^(2/3)]) nx^(1/3))/(
  6.79887*10^17 Sqrt[2.16335*10^-36 + 9.13257*10^-37 nx^(2/3)] + 
   0.64973 nx^(1/3))) + (7.01684*10^20 + 2.77028*10^20/nx^(2/3)) Sqrt[
  1.00854*10^-36 + 4.25755*10^-37 nx^(2/3)] nx + (
 1.17946*10^-16 nx + 9.95818*10^-17 nx^(5/3))/Sqrt[
 1.00854*10^-36 + 4.25755*10^-37 nx^(2/3)]
```

The part that causes the problems is:

```
(7.01684*10^20 + 2.77028*10^20/nx^(2/3))nx
```

Even though it would be easy to simplify by hand, I can't find a way to get Mathematica to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `Piecewise` to define the behaviour for `nx == 0`?

Comment: I ended up using an "If" function at the point it caused problems.

Comment: Try `(7.01684*10^20 + 2.77028*10^20/nx^(2/3)) nx // Expand`what evaluates to `2.77028*10^20 nx^(1/3) + 7.01684*10^20 nx`

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following

```
result = -((1284.57  (0.216577 + (2.0697*10^-19  nx^(1/3))/
          Sqrt[2.16335*10^-36 + 9.13257*10^-37  nx^(2/3)])  nx^(1/
          3))/(6.79887*10^17  Sqrt[
         2.16335*10^-36 + 9.13257*10^-37  nx^(2/3)] + 
       0.64973  nx^(1/3))) + (7.01684*10^20 + 
     2.77028*10^20/nx^(2/3))  Sqrt[
    1.00854*10^-36 + 
     4.25755*10^-37  nx^(2/3)]  nx + (1.17946*10^-16  nx + 
     9.95818*10^-17  nx^(5/3))/
   Sqrt[1.00854*10^-36 + 4.25755*10^-37  nx^(2/3)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

now, instead of

```
 result /. nx -> 0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Do

Thanks to comment below use this limit instead:

`res = SetAccuracy[result, Infinity];`
`Limit[res, nx -> 0]`
`Limit[res, nx -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 However, since the original result was formed with the assumption that `nx > 0` it would be more consistent with `Limit[res, nx -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]`

Comment: @BobHanlon thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Count negative exponents in the complexity function:

```
expr = -((1284.57  (0.216577 + (2.0697*10^-19  nx^(1/3))/
           Sqrt[2.16335*10^-36 + 9.13257*10^-37  nx^(2/3)])  nx^(1/
           3))/(6.79887*10^17  Sqrt[
          2.16335*10^-36 + 9.13257*10^-37  nx^(2/3)] + 
        0.64973  nx^(1/3))) + (7.01684*10^20 + 
      2.77028*10^20/nx^(2/3))  Sqrt[
     1.00854*10^-36 + 
      4.25755*10^-37  nx^(2/3)]  nx + (1.17946*10^-16  nx + 
      9.95818*10^-17  nx^(5/3))/
    Sqrt[1.00854*10^-36 + 4.25755*10^-37  nx^(2/3)];
FullSimplify[expr, nx > 0, 
 ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 
     5 Count[#, Power[nx, _?Negative], Infinity] &)]
% /. nx -> 0

(* 0. *)
```